# PHP Artisan say's vendor's publishing is complete, but it's not

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and facing a strange issue.

I type:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

And got the answer:

```
Publishing complete.
```

However, if I go to /resources/assets/js/components/, there's no vue component.

I'm working with an API, so I need this components to make the control panel that generate tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem: I changed manually the composer.json file, after that I just run:

```
composer update
```

And try to publish again.